# swiftmailer issue with symfony1.4

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I am working on symfony 1.4.
For email i have use swiftmailer.

```
 $this->toAddress = $arrParams['toEmail'];
 $this->bccAddress = $arrParams['bccEmail'];
 $this->subject = $objSiteEmails->getSubject();
 $this->body = $objSiteEmails->getMessageBody();
if (sfConfig::get('app_smtp_flag') == 'On') {
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(sfConfig::get('app_smtp_host'), sfConfig::get('app_smtp_port'), sfConfig::get('app_smtp_security'))
                        ->setUsername(sfConfig::get('app_smtp_username'))
                        ->setPassword(sfConfig::get('app_smtp_password'));
            } else {                  
                $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
            }



 $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
// COMMENT : Replace Common Variable
            $SITE_URL = clsCommon::getSystemConfigVars('SITE_URL');
            $supportEmail = clsCommon::getSystemConfigVars('SUPPORT_EMAIL');
            $SITE_NAME = clsCommon::getSystemConfigVars('SITE_NAME');
            $this->fromEmail = clsCommon::getSystemConfigVars('SITE_EMAIL_FROM');
            $this->fromLabel = clsCommon::getSystemConfigVars('SITE_EMAIL_FROM_LABEL');

            $this->body = preg_replace('/##SITE_URL##/', $SITE_URL, $this->body);
            $this->body = preg_replace('/##SUPPORT_EMAIL##/', $supportEmail, $this->body);
            $this->body = preg_replace('/##SITE_NAME##/', $SITE_NAME, $this->body);

            //Create a message
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($this->subject)
                                        ->setFrom(array($this->fromEmail => $this->fromLabel))
                                        ->setTo($this->toAddress)
                                        ->setBcc($this->bccAddress)
                                        ->addPart($this->body, $this->contentType);
            $mailer->send($message);
```

I have use above code for email send ,
and i have get error as below,

500 | Internal Server Error | Swift_TransportException

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y20sm15170767pfj.26 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Seems like you have entered wrong smtp username and password. Please double check configuration

Comment: What's the port you're using?

Comment: smtp_host:                     'smtp.gmail.com'
 smtp_port:                     '465'
 smtp_security:                 'ssl'